# C# WPF connecting to MongoDB slows window appearence

Tags: c#, wpf, mongodb, window, lag

So, I'm making a WPF app that connects the user to a MongoDB database and stores it in a variable then of course update the database documents etc...
The problem is , when I connect the database in this method:

```cs
public MainWindow() {
            
            InitializeComponent();
            
            //centering window
            WindowStartupLocation = System.Windows.WindowStartupLocation.CenterScreen;
            

            try {
                UpdateChecker.CheckForUpdate(false);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
            }
            Connector.EstablishConnection();
        
        }
```

Here is the Connector method:

```cs
public static void EstablishConnection() {
            try {

                Client = new MongoClient(<my ATLAS link>);
                Database = Client.GetDatabase(DatabaseName);
                Collection = Database.GetCollection<BsonDocument>(CollectionName);

                FirstDocument = Collection.Find(new BsonDocument()).FirstOrDefault();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
            }

        }
```

The window appears after a delay, which is the connection delay. How can I speed up this? Or am I doing this wrong? Is there some other way to connect more efficiently? Should I connect to the database only if I want to use it or just connect to it at the end of the app and close it when the user closes the app?

Answer (score 1):

You can handle the [Loaded](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.frameworkelement.loaded?view=netframework-4.7.2&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Windows.FrameworkElement.Loaded);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%253Dv4.7.2);k(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue) event and call `EstablishConnection` from `Task`.

```
public MainWindow() 
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Loaded += MainWindow_Loaded;
    //centering window
    WindowStartupLocation = System.Windows.WindowStartupLocation.CenterScreen;
    try 
    {
        UpdateChecker.CheckForUpdate(false);
    } 
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
    }        
}

private void MainWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Task.Run(() => Connector.EstablishConnection());
}

public static void EstablishConnection()
{
    try
    {
        Client = new MongoClient(< my ATLAS link >);
        Database = Client.GetDatabase(DatabaseName);
        Collection = Database.GetCollection<BsonDocument>(CollectionName);

        FirstDocument = Collection.Find(new BsonDocument()).FirstOrDefault();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
        }));
    }
}
```

Probably calling `Task.Run(() => Connector.EstablishConnection());` directly from the constructor of `MainWindow` should work.